# Handle Login with Swift/Firebase/Microsoft

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication

Im new with Swift and Im implementing a Login with Firebase and Microsoft Azure AD. After a successful Login, the app returns to the original ViewController instead of showing the WelcomeViewController.
The flow is the following ViewController -> Microsoft Login Form -> Successful Login -> ViewController -> WelcomeViewController.

Here's my code.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var microsoftProvider : OAuthProvider?
let kgraphURI : String! = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}


@IBAction func signIn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.microsoftProvider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")
    self.microsoftProvider?.customParameters =
        ["tenant":"TENANT-ID"]

    self.microsoftProvider?.scopes =
        [
            "profile"
    ]
    self.microsoftProvider?.getCredentialWith(_: nil){
        credential, error in if error != nil{
            // Handle Error
        }
        if let credential = credential{
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential){
                (authResult, error) in if error != nil{
                    // Handle Error
                }
                guard let authResult = authResult else{
                    print("Couldnt get graph result")
                    return
                }
                // Get credential and token when login successfully
                let microCredential = authResult.credential as! OAuthCredential
                let token = microCredential.accessToken!
                // Use token to call Microsoft Graph API

                let welcomeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeViewController") as! WelcomeViewController
                self.view.window?.rootViewController = welcomeViewController
                self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Write this UI related code on main thread

```
  DispatchQueue
      .main.async {

    let welcomeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeViewController") as! WelcomeViewController
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = welcomeViewController
    self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

Comment: does this helps ?

Comment: Hi JawadAli.
I tried to put your snippet right after the successful login but the same behavior, after the login, the ViewController is presented and then it moves forward to the WelcomeViewController.